# Converting a monochrome FreeType bitmap to an 8-bit pixel array

Tags: c++, freetype2

I've spent a few hours trying to convert a monochrome bitmap generated by FreeType to a pixel array that uses 8 bits per pixel (so that I can use them as alpha values for OpenGL). I know I could just get a normal 8bpp bitmap and go with it, but I really need the monochrome version. And I've already tried the method of thresholding pixels, but the result is not at all satisfactory. It seems that once you have the anti-aliased version, you just can't go back.

The snippet below is what I have now, and it's really close to working just right, except for a few letters.

```
if (FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyphIndex, FT_LOAD_MONOCHROME | FT_LOAD_TARGET_MONO))
  throw exception();

if (FT_Render_Glyph(face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_MONO))
  throw exception();

const Size bitmapSize = Size(
    face->glyph->metrics.width / 64, face->glyph->metrics.height / 64
);

u8 *bitmapBits = face->glyph->bitmap.buffer;    
u8 *bitmapBytes = new u8[bitmapSize.width * bitmapSize.height];

memset(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapSize.width * bitmapSize.height);

int width = face->glyph->bitmap.width;
int height = face->glyph->bitmap.rows;

const u8 *src = bitmapBits;

for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row)
{
  u8 *dst = &bitmapBytes[row * width];

  for (int col = 0; col < width / 8; ++col)
  {
      u8 byte = src[col];

      *dst++ = ((byte & (1 << 7)) != 0) ? 255: 0;
      *dst++ = ((byte & (1 << 6)) != 0) ? 255: 0;
      *dst++ = ((byte & (1 << 5)) != 0) ? 255: 0;
      *dst++ = ((byte & (1 << 4)) != 0) ? 255: 0;
      *dst++ = ((byte & (1 << 3)) != 0) ? 255: 0;
      *dst++ = ((byte & (1 << 2)) != 0) ? 255: 0;
      *dst++ = ((byte & (1 << 1)) != 0) ? 255: 0;
      *dst++ = ((byte & (1 << 0)) != 0) ? 255: 0;
  }

  u8 trailingByte = src[width / 8];

  int i = 7;

  switch (width % 8)
  {
  case 7: *dst++ = ((trailingByte & (1 << (i--))) != 0) ? 255 : 0;
  case 6: *dst++ = ((trailingByte & (1 << (i--))) != 0) ? 255 : 0;
  case 5: *dst++ = ((trailingByte & (1 << (i--))) != 0) ? 255 : 0;
  case 4: *dst++ = ((trailingByte & (1 << (i--))) != 0) ? 255 : 0;
  case 3: *dst++ = ((trailingByte & (1 << (i--))) != 0) ? 255 : 0;
  case 2: *dst++ = ((trailingByte & (1 << (i--))) != 0) ? 255 : 0;
  case 1: *dst++ = ((trailingByte & (1 << (i--))) != 0) ? 255 : 0;
  case 0: break;
  }

  src += face->glyph->bitmap.pitch;
}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

I tried to figure out what the distorted letters have in common (maybe that could help me), but I don't know.

Really, I don't know what's wrong with the way I'm doing this. But there must be something I'm missing. Changing the font doesn't fix the problem (except for distorting different letters than before).

**Edit:** I noticed that `face->glyph->bitmap.width` and `face->glyph->bitmap.rows` sometimes return slightly different values than `face->glyph->metrics.width / 64` and `face->glyph->metrics.height / 64`. I've tried switching them around, and the rendering is definitely better, but there are still some characters (like 't' and 'g' with Arial, and 'X' and '0' with Microsoft Sans Serif) that are a bit shifted or distorted.

Arial:
[image]

Microsoft Sans Serif:
[image]

This is really weird and I must be missing something, because I don't believe it's a bug. FreeType seems to be too solid and reliable of a library. Besides, loading fonts as non-monochromatic works perfectly, so this is not a problem with the code that renders the string.

Comment: You could use FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL to get an 8-bit grayscale bitmap suitable for use as an alpha channel, or FT_Bitmap_Convert to convert from the monochrome bitmap to 8-bit. You might also take a look at the [example code](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/example1.c)

Comment: @RetiredNinja The thing is, I need to have the monochrome bitmap (without anti-aliasing), so FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL is out of the question (I've tried using FT_Bitmap_Convert, but no matter what I did, I got gibberish). And I can't just load a normal bitmap and then manually convert it to a monochrome image by thresholding the pixels, because the result is ugly and not as crisp and nice as the monochrome version. You just can't turn back once you have the anti-aliased version. :/

Comment: The funny thing is that even when I feed the raw monochrome bitmap from FreeType to OpenGL (with glTexImage2D and GL_BITMAP), it doesn't work at all (only got black rectangles instead of letters), so it seems there has to be some processing involved, and I almost got it, except for the few letter I have trouble with. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The number of bytes in a row is not necessarily the minimum number that fit the bits in the row, but is reported in the `pitch` field of the bitmap.